# I accidentally moved a .config folder and I don't know where to put it back Ubuntu Cinnamon 21.10 have a pic. Where do i retun it to?

Tags: directory, cinnamon

Somehow while moving files around, I grabbed and dragged a .config folder with lots of clues to where it goes, but I don't know and I am worried if I don't get it back, I will have real problems if this computer shuts down and I am sorting tons of unbacked-up files rn, as well as other things. Please, where does this go? Ubuntu 21.1 cinnamon with some other real problems. Honestly, I want to fix this, back up my data, and re-install,but I need this .config folder back where it belongs!  Also, there is a.config folder near the top folder that has a lot less in it.  sorry to be vague there.  TIA
[image: moved .config folder]

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Ubuntu Cinnamon is a remix and not a flavor; it has it's own support via other media such as telegram*

Comment: Please note you referred to your product a Ubuntu Cinnamon 21.1 once; that would mean you have a *forgery* as no release came out in January (01) with releases only in April (04) & October (10); as they use the *year.month* format as used by Ubuntu and *flavors*.

Comment: Copy it back to the `/home/aliceqd` directory.

Comment: i think @Jennylee make only a typo in his question. the headline points to 21.10. thus the question is on toppic.

Comment: it is official Lemur release.  Must have have typed incorrect version.  Apologies.  I still have two .config files.  One in directory on Home with a few items and one in a folder on my desktop that I know  does not belong therte,but the contents of both .config folder are differnet are different

Answer (score 0):

`.config` is a hidden directory in the user's home directory (`/home/<username>`, symbolized by `~`, accessed with the Home icon in the left bar). So move it back from your `~/Desktop/adiwaits` directory to your home directory.

Comment: yeah, but there is already a folder there marked .config and it haas different contents

Comment: yeah, but you asked where a .config folder normally belongs

Comment: @Jennylee You can remove that one and replace it with the former one: `sudo cp -r ~/Desktop/adiwaits/.config ~/`

Comment: @Someone, do that with sudo, and the ownership will be borked. Can be restored, though.